# Universal way of setting display resolution from a Linux application

Tags: linux, xorg, display, wayland, resolution

I want to set the display resolution before starting a fullscreen window on Linux and I want to do it from inside the application.

The problem is, that I am looking for a universal way to do so, but it seems like xrandr is not capable to change the resolution under Wayland.

Is there any way to set the resolution without resorting to different methods for Xorg and Wayland? I am looking for the most compact solution to this problem, this is why I need a simple and universal approach.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to set the resolution without resorting to different methods for Xorg and Wayland?

None AFAIK. They have completely different APIs despite both nowadays running on top of KMS.